# Change Failed Domain After few Retry Policy .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I have this code, where I'm handling failed network requests with Polly, what I'm wondering if there are a way to change the domain from `https://www.api1.com` to `https://www.api2.com` after a few failover using polly,

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
    .CreateLogger();

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(message => !message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), (result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
    {
        logger.Warning($"Request failed with {result.Result.StatusCode}. Waiting {timeSpan} before 
                         next retry. Retry attempt {retryCount}");
    })
    .ExecuteAsync(() => httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.api1.com"));

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    logger.Informa`enter code here`tion("Response was successful.");
else
    logger.Error($"Response failed. Status code {response.StatusCode}");
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding any other problem conceptual or otherwise. One approach would be to simply change the *url* in `WaitAndRetryAsync`

**Low tech approach ensues**

```
var url1 = "https://postman-echo.com/status/500";
var url2 = "https://postman-echo.com/status/200";

var currentUrl = url1;

var httpClient = new HttpClient();

var response = await Policy
   .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(message => !message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), (result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"Request failed with {result.Result.StatusCode}. Waiting {timeSpan} before next retry.Retry attempt { retryCount}");
      if (retryCount > 2)
      {
         currentUrl = url2;
         Console.WriteLine("Changing to " + currentUrl);
      }
   })
   .ExecuteAsync(() =>
   {
      Console.WriteLine(currentUrl);
      return httpClient.GetAsync(currentUrl);
   });
```

**Output**

```
https://postman-echo.com/status/500
Request failed with InternalServerError. Waiting 00:00:02 before next retry.Retry attempt 1
https://postman-echo.com/status/500
Request failed with InternalServerError. Waiting 00:00:02 before next retry.Retry attempt 2
https://postman-echo.com/status/500
Request failed with InternalServerError. Waiting 00:00:02 before next retry.Retry attempt 3
Changing to https://postman-echo.com/status/200
https://postman-echo.com/status/200
```

<sub>***Disclaimer** : This is not meant to be the bastion of perfect code or a complete solution. Add pepper and salt to taste, and splash of due diligence*. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`</sub>